# How to disconnect wifi link, that was connected with wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I connect with the following command:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D nl80211 -i wlan_card -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/connection.conf
```

It connects fine, and keeps persistent connection. If AP goes down, the connection tears, if AP gets back up, the connection comes back. If I power down the wifi interface:

```
sudo ip link set wlan_card down
```

It goes down. When I bring it up with:

```
sudo ip link set wlan_card up
```

The connection, that was launched in the very beginning with wpa_supplicant, reconnects again.

Such stable, persistent connection is very good, but then it causes a problem, if I want to connect to a different AP.

When I try to use wpa_cli with any command, it just gives me the following error:

```
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
```

When I try to disconnect with:

```
sudo iw dev wlan_card disconnect
```

It disconnects, but reconnects right away, so, currently, I have to reserve to:

```
ps -AlF|grep -i wpa
sudo kill -KILL wpa_pid
```

I wish to know the correct method to stop the connection, or killing is the only way?

Comment: can you add the output of `ps -AlF|grep -i wpa` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before connecting a to a different AP you can stop the running instance of the `wpa_supplicant` service:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

Configure your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/connection.conf` then connect through `wpa_supplicant`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/proper-way-to-disconnect-from-internet-via-command-line-and-wpa_supplicant-4175609038/) you can use `wpa_cli` to disconnect properly by `wpa_cli disconnect` I used `wpa_supplicant` for a long time and I'm pretty sure killing the process will result in failure when you reconnect again.